# Threading progress bar not added to form

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar, infragistics

Trying to create a thread which will modify the window which is generated from the class. It will also start the ultra activity indicator. however when I run this code it will modify the window but will not add the ultra activity monitor and will just have a white rectangle where it would sit.

```
public void refreshNotification()
{
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
        new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(330, 100);
            window.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            window.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise;
            window.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            window.MouseDown += window_MouseDown;
            window.MouseMove += window_MouseMove;
            window.MouseUp += window_MouseUp;
            UltraActivityIndicator Indicator = customiseActivityIndicator();
            window.Controls.Add(Indicator);
            window.Show();
            while (done == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                //do nothing
            }
            Indicator.Stop();
        }
    ));
    backgroundThread.Start();
}

private static UltraActivityIndicator customiseActivityIndicator()
{
    UltraActivityIndicator Indicator = new UltraActivityIndicator();
    Indicator.Start();
    Indicator.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 35);
    Indicator.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(230, 25);
    Indicator.MarqueeAnimationStyle =               Infragistics.Win.UltraActivityIndicator.MarqueeAnimationStyle.BounceBack;
    Indicator.AnimationSpeed = (25);
    Infragistics.Win.Appearance appearance12 = new Infragistics.Win.Appearance();
    appearance12.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;
    Indicator.MarqueeFillAppearance = appearance12;

    return Indicator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your window in separate `Thread` and after you put exactly that `Thread` into unlimit `Sleep` with this code:

```
while (done == false)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    //do nothing
}
```

This is exactly why your window is white - it's busy from the `Windows` point of view.

I suggest you to create your window on UI `Thread` and use the `BeginInvoke` for resizing and indicator logic.